# What is the most important feature in Mono 2.0?

Tags: mono

[Mono 2.0 was just officially released](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page). What single feature do you think is the most important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows.Forms is definitely way up there... that might be the feature I'm most excited about.  And LINQ-to-XML should be good.  I'm looking forward to more LINQ providers now that the LINQ core is available! :)

Answer (score 2):

C# 3.0/LINQ

Answer (score 2):

Complete implementation of System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

The complete .NET 2.0 profile is quite of an accomplishment!